# Jquery ajax problem

Tags: jquery, ajax, live

I have a clickable map of country which is loaded on document ready.

```
    $(document).ready(function bg() {
        $.ajaxSetup ({cache: false,timeout: 5000});     
        $("#map").load("/maps/country.php",function() {
    $('.map').maphilight({SOME SETTINGS HERE});     
    });
});
```

When I click on city it triggers the ajax function which loads the city file to the #map div rebinding bunch of javascript for checkboxes maphover etc...

```
$("#map").load("/maps/cityc_maps.php", function() {

        //JAVASCRIPT NEEDED HERE!

 });
```

The problem that I am having is when I load the city map into the div (with ajax), I'd like to have my script rebind the scripts (and highlight that portion of the map).

```
$("#map").load("/maps/cityc_maps.php", function() {

        //JAVASCRIPT NEEDED HERE!

 $("#CountryLink").load("/maps/country.php",function() {
  $('.map').maphilight({SOME SETTINGS HERE});
    //AND HERE WHEN USER CLICK CITY MAP when file load
 });

 });
```

It's very confusing but I hope someone will understand me.  I think the solution is reloading the page but I hope there is way to make it with ajax.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem you have. Why don't you create an extra link on page load that loads the country map? It could also be that your problem can be solved by just using named functions instead of anonymous functions.

Comment: Without knowing what sort of system you're using we can't really help you. This is a very practical question and without having the identical circumstance I highly doubt you're gonna get a solution. If you want a theoretical solution on each country load, save the country so the user can go back to that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to bind event handlers to elements inserted via AJAX, I think you should use `live`:
http://api.jquery.com/live/

This way, you bind event handlers once in your JavaScript code and jQuery takes care of observing new bindable elements.